# sum all value in foreach loop php

Tags: php

```
 <?php  foreach((array)$query as $row):?>
  <td><?php echo $row->date ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row->cost ?></td>
  <?php endforeach ;?>
```

I want to sum all values in `$row->cost` when `$row->date=02-01-2016`, like this in a table
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: This question does not contain a clear [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

```
<?php 
$total = 0;
foreach((array)$query as $row):
    $date = $row->date;
    $cost = $row->cost;
    if(date("M-d-Y", strtotime($date))==date("M-d-Y")) {
        $total = $total+$cost;
    }
    ?>
    <td><?php echo $date ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $cost ?></td>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<td colspan="2"><?php echo $total; ?></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo array_sum(array_filter(array_map(function($row){
  if($row->date == '02-01-2016')
    return $row->cost;
}, $array)));
```

You can use

- [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php): to compare and skip the values for which cost is not needed to add in sum.
- [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php): and then to remove the blank indexes
- [`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php): and finally to sum cost

Note: if you are getting results from database, you can simply do sum there (see below):

```
$db->query("SELECT SUM(costs) FROM table_name WHERE `date`='2016-01-02'");
echo $db->fetchColumn();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$tot = 0;
foreach( (array)$query as $row ) {
    if( $row->date=='02-01-2016' ) $tot = $tot+$row->cost;
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row->date ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->cost ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
<tr><td colspan="2"><?php echo $tot; ?></td></tr>
```

obviously, the comparison works if `$row->date` is formatted as `dd-mm-yyyy`

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border=1>
<?php
$tot = 0;
foreach($query as $row ) {
    if( $row->date=='2016-01-02' ) $tot += $row->cost;
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row->date ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->cost ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
<tr><td></td><td><?php echo $total; ?></td></tr>
</table>
```

It will work for you exctly what u want.